# Add Environment variable to Docker file that Contains :

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to add some environment variables to  dockerfile which contains :

SO I need to add something like

```
environment:
 -OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider=true
```

any idea how to do that , I even tried to surround the key with "" but it fails to so if any idea , and docker compose file it gives error on :

Comment: Did you mean to type `ture`?  Are you sure you didn't mean `true`?  Additionally, is this for your `Dockerfile` or a `docker-compose.yml` file?  Also, explain what you mean by "fails".  How do you know it fails?

Comment: @zero298 docker-compose.yml  it gives error in :

Comment: Can you post the full yaml

Comment: Try with `env_file` option https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `env_file` option of docker-compose.

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) out.

Here is what I tried and it worked:

- Created `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  distro:
    env_file: test.env
    image: alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: Alpine_Distro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
```

- Created `test.env` file.

```
OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider=true
```

- Ran `docker-compose up -d`

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "ttt_default" with the default driver
Pulling distro (alpine:)...
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
921b31ab772b: Pull complete
Creating Alpine_Distro ... done
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.33 ~/ttt
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS NAMES
74ee753a27b6        alpine              "tail -f /dev/null"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds Alpine_Distro
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.33 ~/ttt
$ docker exec -it 74ee753a27b6 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=74ee753a27b6
TERM=xterm
OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider=true
HOME=/root
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.33 ~/ttt
```

**NOTE:** As you can see `OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider=true` env variable is properly set.

Here your environment variable contains `:` in it, so I guess that's why `environment` field was not working for you. In `env_file` option whatever is on left hand side of `=` is considered as environment name and right hand side -f `=` as the value. So its `key=value` syntax in `env_file` that's why it will work.

Hope this helps.

Update:

In case you are using only plain `docker` use [--env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) option of `docker run`

```
$ docker run -itd --env-file test.env alpine
74f60cb6f513519c2dd7a093622537215937db1682b79a838c95e944a649f451
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS NAMES
74f60cb6f513        alpine              "/bin/sh"             12 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds infallible_nobel
$ docker exec -it 74f60cb6f513 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=74f60cb6f513
TERM=xterm
OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider=true
HOME=/root
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put quotes, I checked it with:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENV "OAuth2Configuration:CacheProvider"=true 
CMD ["env"]
```

Comment: I use docker compose I  tried "OAuth2Configuration:CachingEnabled"=${CachingEnabled} it gives error expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'